# «Время года» — это подлежащее?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

**Синтаксический разбор предложения: "Моё любимое время года это осень"**

Помогите, пожалуйста, очень нужно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вы забыли поставить тире: «Мое любимое время года **—** это осень».

Во-вторых, главные члены этого предложения: подлежащее — *время года*, сказуемое — *осень*. Второстепенные — определения *мое*, *любимое*.